# Reopen a php7.2 session in a long-running Eventsource script?

Tags: php, session-state, server-sent-events, php-7.2

I have a new error when calling `session_start()` since upgrading to php7.2:

> PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in Example.php on line 20

This warning prevents writing to the session. This occurs in long-running php scripts that I used for Eventsource (Server Sent Events). To respond to certain events, the script should update a session value. This code worked on php7.

Example:

```
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream\n\n");
session_start();
session_write_close();

$i = 0;
while(true){

sleep(3);
// At some point new information is retrieved

$NewValue = $i++;

if ($NewValue % 2 == 0){
$SomethingInterestingHappened = true;
}else{
$SomethingInterestingHappened = false;
}

if($SomethingInterestingHappened){
session_start();  // <- this line throws error
$_SESSION['CurrentRecord'] = $NewValue;
session_write_close();
}

// Writes cool things to browser

}
```

Does anyone know of a way to make this work with native php7.2? Or recommendations for third-party solutions?

I found [bug reports](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74941) that may be relevant.

**Update:** Added working code example in case someone wants to test it.

Comment: Rather then spending a day or two redesigning a web app. I rolled back to php7.0. I tried php7.1. It failed as well. Both php7.0 and php7.1 give the same error messages (different than the php7.2 error); however, the sessions actually update in php7.0. Here's what 7.0/7.01 say: PHP Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent. And: PHP Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent.

Comment: It's strange that this specific error pops up precisely under PHP/7.2. It it possible that, upon upgrade, you inadvertently changed the error reporting settings? In any case: 1) Having two Unix line feeds at the end of the `Content-Type` header feels definitively wrong. 2) URL-based session transmission (as per the bug report) is terribly insecure.

Comment: The two linefeeds are what delimit the messages in Eventsource. I'm pretty sure that's done correctly. I followed a MDN article. As for the sessions, I am using cookie sessions. URL/form sessions are disabled. Basically I need a function that writes to the session file without worrying about cookies. I'll probably have to write my own or just upgrade to better session management, which is on my agenda anyways.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I somehow managed to misread the Server Sent Events part.